# Getting Ids of persons where related table data matches condition

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have a schenario where I have to collect ids of persons whose task states match a condition:

There are Tables Person, Task and Schedule. Relevant fields are:

```
Person.Id

Schedule.Id
Schedule.StartDate
Schedule.EndDate

Task.Id
Task.ScheduleId
Task.PersonId
Task.State
```

In this case Person has scheduled tasks, 12 in total, each having a schedule, so 12 rows in Schedule per Person, 1 Task per each Schedule. Schedules are typically few days long, never overlapping.

Task can have 1 of 6 different states, 2 of them being **StateX** and **StateEmpty**.

I need to collect - using ef and linq - those patients who have 2 latest Tasks in StateX, or those patients who have latest Task in StateX, then one in StateEmpty and then one again in StateX. So either 2 latest tasks in StateX or one StateEmpty in between to latest tasks in StateX.

For example:

```
Task.Id     Task.State  Schedule times
1           StateX      2018-09-01 - 2018-09-05
2           StateX      2018-08-01 - 2018-08-05     -- matches

3           StateX      2018-09-01 - 2018-09-05
4           StateZ      2018-08-01 - 2018-08-05     -- doesn't match

5           StateX      2018-09-01 - 2018-09-05
6           StateEmtpy  2018-08-01 - 2018-08-05
7           StateZ      2018-07-01 - 2018-07-05     -- doesn't match

8           StateX      2018-09-01 - 2018-09-05
9           StateEmpty  2018-08-01 - 2018-08-05
10          StateX      2018-07-01 - 2018-07-05     -- matches
```

Problem is I cannot use a query like entities.Tasks.Include(c => c.Schedules), the query doesn't give me Schedules to link the tables. All I can work with is separate lists of Tasks and Schedules. Dbcontext is different in these queries and data is retrieved using different db connections, this is something I cannot change.

I can do something like:

```
var schedules = scheduleEntities.Schedules.Where(s => s.StartTime > somedate && s.EndDate < DateTime.Now).ToList();
var ids = schedules.Select(s => s.Id).ToList();
var tasks = taskEntities.Tasks.Where(t => ids.Contains(t.ScheduleId) && (t.State == StateX || t.State == StateEmpty)).ToList();
```

... and use loops and ifs to match the condition and collect the Person Ids to a list.

But that doesn't seem like the best possible I'd want to solve the problem. I would like to make sure performance is not an issue and the code is readable and clear.

How would you solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can try something like this:

```
var joinQuery =
    from schedule in scheduleEntities.Schedules
    join task in taskEntities.Tasks on schedule.Id equals task.ScheduleId
    where schedule.StartTime > somedate && schedule.EndDate < DateTime.Now &&  (task.State == StateX || task.State == StateEmpty)
    select new { PersonId = task.PersonId};
```

Be indulgent I did not test it but the idea is there.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Sébastien,

Your example got me to a solution I'm happy with, at least based on small scale testing, here's what I came up with:

I just added an order by and a group by to help process the result.

```
List<string> patientIds = new List<string>();
var schedules = scheduleEntities.schedules.Where(s => s.StartTime > somedate && s.EndDate < DateTime.Now).ToList();
var tasks = taskEntities.Tasks.ToList();

var items =
    from schedule in schedules
    join task in tasks on schedule.Id equals task.ScheduleId
    orderby schedule.StartTime descending
    select new { task.PersonId, schedule.StartTime, task.State };
var itemgroups = items.GroupBy(i => i.PersonId).ToList();

foreach (var item in itemgroups)
{
    if ((item.Count() >= 2 && (item.ElementAt(0).State == "StateX" && item.ElementAt(1).State == "StateX"))
        ||
        (item.Count() >= 3 && (item.ElementAt(0).State == "StateX" && item.ElementAt(1).State == "StateEmpty" && item.ElementAt(2).State == "StateX")))
    {
        patientIds.Add(item.Key);
    }
}
```